# JavaFX Stage open on specific Screen - weird behavior

Tags: javafx

I open a stage using following code:

```
ObservableList<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreens();
   if(screens.size()>1){
         Rectangle2D rec = screens.get(preferredScreen).getVisualBounds();
         stage.setX(rec.getMinX());
         stage.setY(rec.getMinY());   
   }
```

When this is called from a window at primary screen, this works perfectly.

When this is called from a  non-primary screen, the stage opens on preferred screen and then jumps to the screen where the mouse is in.

Seems to me being a Windows "feature". What would be the best way get this window to the right screen?

Comment: How is your monitor setup? Extended, duplicated, or show only at one?

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc of [Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html), you should set the new stage relative to the primary screen, because you only extend your desktop. So you should write something like this:

```
    int preferredScreen = 1;
    double offsetX = 0;
    double offsetY = 0;

    Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();

    ObservableList<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreens();
   if(screens.size()>1){
         Rectangle2D rec = screens.get(preferredScreen).getVisualBounds();
         // upper left corner of the extended screen
         offsetX = rec.getMinX();
         offsetY = rec.getMinY();
         // set relative to this screen
         stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX() + offsetX);
         stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY() + offsetY);   
   }
```

Can't test it by myself, I only have one monitor.