# I get a white screen when i am trying to pass a Label from First Screen to Second Screen?

Tags: javafx

I am having a serious problem when i am trying to pass from First Screen Stage a Label to Second Screen. Important staff is if in my code i choose  to open that stage not in second Screen but in the fist the thing works but if a put to the second screen i get a white Stage and i dont know what i´m doing wrong, please help me!

```
  public void FullScreen() throws IOException {
        List<Screen> allScreens = Screen.getScreens();
        //if (allScreens.size() > 1) {
        Screen secondaryScreen = allScreens.get(1); // if i change this to 0 it works but i get the stage in the first Screen.
        Rectangle2D bounds = secondaryScreen.getVisualBounds();
        b.setEy(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DoileaMonitor.fxml")));
        ThingUp.root.getChildren().remove(getLblStrofe());// main stage
        getLblStrofe().setLayoutX(bounds.getMinX());
        getLblStrofe().setLayoutY(bounds.getMinY());
        getLblStrofe().setPrefSize(bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
        b.getEy().getChildren().add(getLblStrofe());//second stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(b.getEy());

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
//      stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
        // }
    }
```

Comment: What type of Display settings you use? Extend, Duplicate or Show only on? If you use Extend, then you need to be relativ to your primary screen. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31160564/4170073

Comment: I am using a extented screen. I tried ur solution and still get the same result a grey/white screen. In first screen with my code works but in second not. What a pitty!